# ¿Cuándo usar "excusa" o "pretexto"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Aparentemente, "excusa" y "pretexto" significan lo mismo.

¿Cuándo usar uno o el otro? Por ejemplo, comparando estas 2 frases:

- Buscó una **excusa** para no venir.
- Buscó un **pretexto** para no venir.

¿Tienen el mismo significado? ¿Cuál sería más correcta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En muchas ocasiones son intercambiables, pero «pretexto» siempre tiene la connotación de ser una excusa falsa o simulada. Por contra, la excusa *puede* ser o no falsa. Ojo, que es «excusa», con equis.

[Según la Fundación del Español Urgente](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendaciones-E-excusa-y-pretexto-no-siempre-son-sinonimos-469.html):

> Un pretexto es 'una excusa falsa', 'una causa simulada que
>   aparentemente se alega para hacer, o no hacer, algo'. Una excusa puede
>   ser falsa o verdadera; 'es un motivo que se presenta como
>   justificación para eludir una responsabilidad; pudiendo ser, o no, la
>   justificación real de la disculpa'.

En cuanto a tus ejemplos, «Buscó un pretexto para no venir» y «Buscó una excusa para no venir», diría que en este caso son completamente equivalentes. Si en ambos casos la justificación es algo *buscado*, entonces el verdadero motivo es otro, y la excusa proporcionada es falsa, luego también es pretexto. Ambas frases valdrían.

Por resumir:

- si el motivo es falso, inventado o supuesto, puedes usar ambas palabras.
- si el motivo es verdadero, solo puedes usar «excusa» (u otras palabras, como «motivo», «causa», «explicación»...).

Comment: Pretexto y excusa las dos pueden ser falsas, simuladas y no verdaderas. El diccionario RAE dice de pretexto: 1. m. Motivo o causa simulada o aparente que se alega para hacer algo o para excusarse de no haberlo ejecutado. El mátiz de la diferencia hay que buscarlo por otro lado. Y si un motivo es verdadero no es un pretexto, un motivo verdadero es un motivo verdadero, o una justificación real, pero al ser verdadero y no ser simulado no es un pretexto. http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=pretexto

Comment: Exactamente, es lo que digo. «Pretexto» siempre es falso. «Excusa», a veces sí, a veces no. Ese es el matiz.

Comment: Pretexto no siempre es falso. Existe un uso de pretexto con el apellido de legítimo e incluso sin el, en el cual el pretexto no puede ser considerado como algo falso o simulado sino como una justificación totalmente válida.

Comment: http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretexto

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero No según la RAE, la Fundéu, el uso en otros idiomas y la propia [etimología de la palabra](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pretexto). Si buscas el inglés «pretext», el francés «prétexte», el italiano «pretesto», el portugués «pretexto» o el original en latín «praetextus», verás que siempre llevan la connotación negativa de _cubrir_ y _adornar_ algo.

Comment: Aun cubriendo o adornando algo, el pretexto no significa que sea falso como decías anteriormente. De hecho el orgigen latino de la palabra tiene que ver con legitmidad. con la toga que usaban los magistrados.